# variable in Search pattern of awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file env_prop like below

```
Generic|HOSTNAME|UKLOSOLD
Generic|FileServerPort|42501
Generic|HubPort|45203
mlc|murexnetport|45204
mlc|DatabaseName|PX_abc02
Replicate|ReplicateForm|pxabc01
Replicate|ReplicateTo|hxxyz02
```

I want my output should be like below, uniquely sorting from the field 1

```
****  Generic Parameters  ****

HOSTNAME                  UKLOSOLD                      
FileServerPort            42501                         
HubPort                   45203                         

****  mlc Parameters  ****

murexnetport              45204                         
DatabaseName              px_abc02                    

****  Replicate Parameters  ****

ReplicateForm             pxabc01                      
ReplicateTo               hxxyz02
```

but my prog does not give the required result could you please help on it

```
for val in `cat env_prop|cut -d'|' -f1|uniq`
do
echo "****  ${val} Parameters  ****"
printf "\n"
awk -F"|" "/$val/ {printf "%-25s %-30s\n", $2 , $3}" env_prop
printf "\n"
done
```

Causing problem in awk statement in the printf section

Comment: Avoid using old and deprecated back-tics, use parentheses like this: `for val in $(cat env_prop|cut -d'|' -f1|uniq)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F '\\|' '{a[$1]=sprintf("%s%s%-25s %-30s", a[$1], ORS, $2, $3)} END {
    for (i in a) printf ORS "****  %s Parameters  ****%s%s" ORS, i, ORS, a[i]}' file

****  Replicate Parameters  ****

ReplicateForm             pxabc01
ReplicateTo               hxxyz02

****  Generic Parameters  ****

HOSTNAME                  UKLOSOLD
FileServerPort            42501
HubPort                   45203

****  mlc Parameters  ****

murexnetport              45204
DatabaseName              PX_abc02
```

Comment: is there any way to change inside the {printf "%-25s %-30s\n", $2 , $3} so that result will display from my program

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid awk with

```
lastheader=""
while IFS=\| read header key value; do
        if [ -z "${value}" ]; then
                continue
        fi
        if [ "${header}" != "${lastheader}" ]; then
                if [ -n "${lastheader}" ]; then
                        echo
                fi
                printf "**** %s Parameters ****\n\n" "${header}"
                lastheader="${header}"
        fi
        printf "%-20s %s\n" "$key" "$value"
done < env_prop
```

EDIT: Removed `cat env_prop |`, replaced by < env_prop

Comment: Thanks Anubhava and Walter

Comment: When you happy accept an answer from @Anubhava or me, maybe upvote the other.

Answer (score 0):

This will keep the file in order:

```
awk -F'|' '
  $1 != prev {print "\n****  " $1 " parameters ****\n"; prev = $1}
  {printf "%-25s%s\n", $2, $3}
' file
```

```
****  Generic parameters ****

HOSTNAME            UKLOSOLD
FileServerPort      42501
HubPort             45203

****  mlc parameters ****

murexnetport        45204
DatabaseName        PX_abc02

****  Replicate parameters ****

ReplicateForm       pxabc01
ReplicateTo         hxxyz02
```

The problem with what you were doing: using double quotes aroung the awk body will allow the shell to substitute **its** `$2` and `$3`

```
awk -F"|" "/$val/ {printf "%-25s %-30s\n", $2 , $3}" env_prop
```

You would want:

```
awk -F"|" -v patt="^${val}$" '$1 ~ patt {printf "%-25s %-30s\n", $2 , $3}'
```

- awk pattern matching with the  `~` operator
- single quotes around the awk body
- `-v` option to pass a shell variable into awk as an awk variable

But, as demonstrated, only a single pass through the file is required: don't need shell loops or use of `cut`.